# Materialising a graph within an actor

Tags: scala, akka, actor, akka-stream

I am trying to materialise a graph within an actor. This seems to work if either of the following are true:

1. The graph does not contain a broadcast (created with `alsoTo`), or
2. The same `ActorMaterializer` is used for each materialisation, or
3. The graph is materialised outside of an `Actor`

I have reduced it down to the following test cases:

```
import java.util.concurrent.{CountDownLatch, TimeUnit}

import akka.NotUsed
import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorSystem}
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{RunnableGraph, Sink, Source}
import akka.testkit.{TestActorRef, TestKit}

import org.scalatest.{FlatSpecLike, Matchers}

class ActorFlowTest extends TestKit(ActorSystem("ActorFlowTest")) with Matchers with FlatSpecLike {

  def createGraph(withBroadcast: Boolean) = {
    if (withBroadcast) Source.empty.alsoTo(Sink.ignore).to(Sink.ignore)
    else Source.empty.to(Sink.ignore)
  }

  case object Bomb

  class FlowActor(
    graph: RunnableGraph[NotUsed],
    latch: CountDownLatch,
    materializer: (ActorSystem) => ActorMaterializer
  ) extends Actor {

    override def preStart(): Unit = {
      graph.run()(materializer(context.system))
      latch.countDown()
    }

    override def receive: Receive = {
      case Bomb => throw new RuntimeException
    }
  }

  "Without an actor" should "be able to materialize twice" in {
    val graph = Source.empty.alsoTo(Sink.ignore).to(Sink.ignore)
    val materializer1 = ActorMaterializer()(system)
    val materializer2 = ActorMaterializer()(system)
    graph.run()(materializer1)
    graph.run()(materializer2) // Pass
  }

  "With a the same materializer" should "be able to materialize twice" in {
    val graph = createGraph(withBroadcast = true)
    val latch = new CountDownLatch(2)
    val materializer = ActorMaterializer()(system)
    val actorRef = TestActorRef(new FlowActor(graph, latch, _ => materializer))
    verify(actorRef, latch) should be(true) // Pass
  }

  "With a new materializer but no broadcast" should "be able to materialize twice" in {
    val graph = createGraph(withBroadcast = false)
    val latch = new CountDownLatch(2)
    def materializer(system: ActorSystem) = ActorMaterializer()(system)
    val actorRef = TestActorRef(new FlowActor(graph, latch, materializer))
    verify(actorRef, latch) should be(true) // Pass
  }

  "With a new materializer and a broadcast" should "be able to materialize twice" in {
    val graph = createGraph(withBroadcast = true)
    val latch = new CountDownLatch(2)
    def materializer(system: ActorSystem) = ActorMaterializer()(system)
    val actorRef = TestActorRef(new FlowActor(graph, latch, materializer))
    verify(actorRef, latch) should be(true) // Fail
  }

  def verify(actorRef: TestActorRef[_], latch: CountDownLatch): Boolean = {
    actorRef.start()
    actorRef ! Bomb
    latch.await(25, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
  }
}
```

It seems that the last cases will always timeout with the following error in the log:

```
[ERROR] [07/05/2016 16:06:30.625] [ActorFlowTest-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6] [akka://ActorFlowTest/user/$$c] Futures timed out after [20000 milliseconds]
akka.actor.PostRestartException: akka://ActorFlowTest/user/$$c: exception post restart (class java.lang.RuntimeException)
    at akka.actor.dungeon.FaultHandling$$anonfun$6.apply(FaultHandling.scala:250)
    at akka.actor.dungeon.FaultHandling$$anonfun$6.apply(FaultHandling.scala:248)
    at akka.actor.dungeon.FaultHandling$$anonfun$handleNonFatalOrInterruptedException$1.applyOrElse(FaultHandling.scala:303)
    at akka.actor.dungeon.FaultHandling$$anonfun$handleNonFatalOrInterruptedException$1.applyOrElse(FaultHandling.scala:298)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36)
    at akka.actor.dungeon.FaultHandling$class.finishRecreate(FaultHandling.scala:248)
    at akka.actor.dungeon.FaultHandling$class.faultRecreate(FaultHandling.scala:76)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.faultRecreate(ActorCell.scala:374)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invokeAll$1(ActorCell.scala:464)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.systemInvoke(ActorCell.scala:483)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processAllSystemMessages(Mailbox.scala:282)
    at akka.testkit.CallingThreadDispatcher.process$1(CallingThreadDispatcher.scala:243)
    at akka.testkit.CallingThreadDispatcher.runQueue(CallingThreadDispatcher.scala:283)
    at akka.testkit.CallingThreadDispatcher.systemDispatch(CallingThreadDispatcher.scala:191)
    at akka.actor.dungeon.Dispatch$class.restart(Dispatch.scala:119)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.restart(ActorCell.scala:374)
    at akka.actor.LocalActorRef.restart(ActorRef.scala:406)
    at akka.actor.SupervisorStrategy.restartChild(FaultHandling.scala:365)
    at akka.actor.OneForOneStrategy.processFailure(FaultHandling.scala:518)
    at akka.actor.SupervisorStrategy.handleFailure(FaultHandling.scala:303)
    at akka.actor.dungeon.FaultHandling$class.handleFailure(FaultHandling.scala:263)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.handleFailure(ActorCell.scala:374)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invokeAll$1(ActorCell.scala:459)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.systemInvoke(ActorCell.scala:483)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processAllSystemMessages(Mailbox.scala:282)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:223)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:234)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [20000 milliseconds]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:219)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$result$1.apply(package.scala:190)
    at akka.dispatch.MonitorableThreadFactory$AkkaForkJoinWorkerThread$$anon$3.block(ThreadPoolBuilder.scala:167)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.managedBlock(ForkJoinPool.java:3640)
    at akka.dispatch.MonitorableThreadFactory$AkkaForkJoinWorkerThread.blockOn(ThreadPoolBuilder.scala:165)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$.result(package.scala:190)
    at akka.stream.impl.ActorMaterializerImpl.actorOf(ActorMaterializerImpl.scala:207)
    at akka.stream.impl.ActorMaterializerImpl$$anon$2.matGraph(ActorMaterializerImpl.scala:166)
    at akka.stream.impl.ActorMaterializerImpl$$anon$2.materializeAtomic(ActorMaterializerImpl.scala:150)
    at akka.stream.impl.MaterializerSession$$anonfun$materializeModule$1.apply(StreamLayout.scala:919)
    at akka.stream.impl.MaterializerSession$$anonfun$materializeModule$1.apply(StreamLayout.scala:915)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Set$Set1.foreach(Set.scala:94)
    at akka.stream.impl.MaterializerSession.materializeModule(StreamLayout.scala:915)
    at akka.stream.impl.MaterializerSession$$anonfun$materializeModule$1.apply(StreamLayout.scala:922)
    at akka.stream.impl.MaterializerSession$$anonfun$materializeModule$1.apply(StreamLayout.scala:915)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Set$Set4.foreach(Set.scala:200)
    at akka.stream.impl.MaterializerSession.materializeModule(StreamLayout.scala:915)
    at akka.stream.impl.MaterializerSession.materialize(StreamLayout.scala:882)
    at akka.stream.impl.ActorMaterializerImpl.materialize(ActorMaterializerImpl.scala:182)
    at akka.stream.impl.ActorMaterializerImpl.materialize(ActorMaterializerImpl.scala:80)
    at akka.stream.scaladsl.RunnableGraph.run(Flow.scala:351)
    at ActorFlowTest$FlowActor.preStart(ActorFlowTest.scala:40)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.postRestart(Actor.scala:566)
    at ActorFlowTest$FlowActor.postRestart(ActorFlowTest.scala:33)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundPostRestart(Actor.scala:504)
    at ActorFlowTest$FlowActor.aroundPostRestart(ActorFlowTest.scala:33)
    at akka.actor.dungeon.FaultHandling$class.finishRecreate(FaultHandling.scala:239)
    ... 25 more
```

I have tried explicitly terminating the `ActorMaterializers` but that doesn't reproduce the problem.

A workaround is to create a closure around the `ActorMaterializer` in the `Props` but if this also came from another `Actor` I'm worried I will eventually get similar problems.

Any idea why this is? Obviously it is something to do with the `ActorMaterializer` but interesting how removing the Broadcast also solves it (even with a much more complicated graph).

Comment: Can you try to override postRestart and validate what happens there (check incoming exception and see if the code reaches it)? Also don't forget to call preStart, when overriding postRestart.

Comment: The `RuntimeException` that is thrown in the `receive` is the `reason` in `postRestart`. The `TimeoutException` is thrown when `postRestart` calls `preStart` and when that calls `graph.run`.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be related to (or at least solved through proper) supervision. I created an extra `Supervisor`-Actor which for demonstration purposes just starts a single `FlowActor` in its `preStart` function and forwards the `Bomb` messages to it. The following tests execute successfully without any timeout exception:

```
import java.util.concurrent.{CountDownLatch, TimeUnit}

import akka.NotUsed
import akka.actor.Actor.Receive
import akka.actor.SupervisorStrategy._
import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorRef, ActorSystem, OneForOneStrategy, Props}
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{RunnableGraph, Sink, Source}
import akka.testkit.{TestActorRef, TestKit}
import org.scalatest.{FlatSpecLike, Matchers}

import scala.concurrent.duration._

class ActorFlowTest extends TestKit(ActorSystem("TrikloSystem")) with Matchers with FlatSpecLike {

  def createGraph(withBroadcast: Boolean) = {
    if (withBroadcast) Source.empty.alsoTo(Sink.ignore).to(Sink.ignore)
    else Source.empty.to(Sink.ignore)
  }

  case object Bomb

  class Supervisor( graph: RunnableGraph[NotUsed],
                    latch: CountDownLatch,
                    materializer: (ActorSystem) => ActorMaterializer) extends Actor {

    var actorRef: Option[ActorRef] = None

    override def preStart(): Unit = {
      actorRef = Some(context.actorOf(Props( new FlowActor(graph, latch, materializer))))
    }

    override def receive: Receive = {
      case Bomb => actorRef.map( _ ! Bomb )
    }
  }

  class FlowActor(
                   graph: RunnableGraph[NotUsed],
                   latch: CountDownLatch,
                   materializer: (ActorSystem) => ActorMaterializer
                 ) extends Actor {

    override def preStart(): Unit = {
      graph.run()(materializer(context.system))
      latch.countDown()
    }

    override def receive: Receive = {
      case Bomb =>
        throw new RuntimeException
    }
  }

  "Without an actor" should "be able to materialize twice" in {
    val graph = Source.empty.alsoTo(Sink.ignore).to(Sink.ignore)
    val materializer1 = ActorMaterializer()(system)
    val materializer2 = ActorMaterializer()(system)
    graph.run()(materializer1)
    graph.run()(materializer2) // Pass
  }

  "With a the same materializer" should "be able to materialize twice" in {
    val graph = createGraph(withBroadcast = true)
    val latch = new CountDownLatch(2)
    val materializer = ActorMaterializer()(system)
    val actorRef = TestActorRef(new Supervisor(graph, latch, _ => materializer))
    verify(actorRef, latch) should be(true) // Pass
  }

  "With a new materializer but no broadcast" should "be able to materialize twice" in {
    val graph = createGraph(withBroadcast = false)
    val latch = new CountDownLatch(2)
    def materializer(system: ActorSystem) = ActorMaterializer()(system)
    val actorRef = TestActorRef(new Supervisor(graph, latch, materializer))
    verify(actorRef, latch) should be(true) // Pass
  }

  "With a new materializer and a broadcast" should "be able to materialize twice" in {
    val graph = createGraph(withBroadcast = true)
    val latch = new CountDownLatch(2)
    def materializer(system: ActorSystem) = ActorMaterializer()(system)
    val actorRef = TestActorRef(new Supervisor(graph, latch, materializer))
    verify(actorRef, latch) should be(true) // Fail
  }

  def verify(actorRef: TestActorRef[_], latch: CountDownLatch): Boolean = {
    actorRef.start()
    actorRef ! Bomb
    latch.await(25, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
  }
}
```

Comment: This is useful but it only seems to add to list of caveats. Why would the user guardian actor be any different to the supervisor here? In other words how does this (or any of the other caveats) really change the behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

There are some mis-uses of the Akka TestKit in this test.

`TestActorRef` is a very special test construct in that it will execute on the calling thread (`CallingThreadDispatcher`), to allow for easy synchronous unit testing. Using `CountDownLatch` in a synchronous test is weird since any action is on the same thread so there is no need for inter-thread communication.

When you create an instance of `TestActorRef` it is started in that same call (you can see this by for example throwing an exception from the constructor or `preStart` and see it end up in your test case).

Calling start on the `ActorRef` is definitely not something you should do, `TestActorRef`s special nature gives you access to it, but you are essentially calling start on an empty shell actor, and not the actor you think you are interacting with (and if it was that actor it would stil be wrong to ever call `start()` on it).

A proper (but not very useful since there is no a problem materializing a graph twice regardless of context or materializer) test of what you intend to repeat test would be without the latch and look something like this:

```
class FlowActor(graph: RunnableGraph[NotUsed], materializer: (ActorSystem) => ActorMaterializer) extends Actor {
  override def preStart(): Unit = {
    graph.run()(materializer(context.system))
  }
  override def receive: Receive = Actor.emptyBehavior
}

"With a new materializer and a broadcast" should "be able to materialize twice" in {
  val graph = Source.empty.alsoTo(Sink.ignore).to(Sink.ignore)
  def materializer(system: ActorSystem) = ActorMaterializer()(system)
  val actorRef1 = TestActorRef(new FlowActor(graph, materializer))
  val actorRef2 = TestActorRef(new FlowActor(graph, materializer))
  // we'd get an exception here if it was not possible to materialize
  // since pre-start is run on the calling thread - the same thread
  // that is executing the test case
}
```

I'd just let the specific weirdnesses of this go instead of digging deeper into the magic in `TestActorRef`, it will be hard earned insights and they will not be applicable in many cases but this specific one.